# How to send notifications to selected Sellers, when order is made?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm new in `SignalR` and I can't find anywhere help for how to send notifications to users. The task is like this: Client can order from multiple sellers at one time, like `Aliexpress` or `eBay`, I need when order is made, how to notify the sellers for the new order.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) is short and good explanation with practical example about what SignalR is.

But in this example all the messages are broadcasting to all clients - that's not what you need in your task. In other words you need to replace following line of code in `ChatHub` class:

```
Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
```

with something like:

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
```

In [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#in-memory-storage) you can find several ways of sending messages between users.
I would recommend "In-memory storage" approach because I have successfully implemented kind of that way while had troubles with SignalR's `Groups`.